# Apache Cannot See PM2 Node Process

Tags: apache-2.2, reverse-proxy, node.js, pm2

I have Apache running on Ubuntu 20 and I keep getting this error in `/var/logs/apache2/error.log`:

```
[proxy:error] [pid 7064] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: http: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:4000 (127.0.0.1) failed

[proxy_http:error] [pid 7064] [client ...] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: 127.0.0.1
```

My virtual host is set up like this:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin me@example.com
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

RewriteEngine on

# Reverse Proxy Stuff for Node
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:4000/ Keepalive=On
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:4000/ Keepalive=On

SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

In my web directory (`/var/www/example.com`) I started my app with pm2 like this:

```
pm2 start index.js -p 4000
```

When I do `pm2 status` I see that my process is online. There are no errors in `pm2 logs`. Somehow Apache and pm2 aren't talking to each other.

`netstat -tulpn` confirms that nothing is listening on port 4000.

I don't know what else to do. Any ideas?

Comment: According to PM2 guide you do not have key `-p`. Better add `--log` and check generated logs

Comment: Ah, you're right! My bad. Looks like doing `port=4000 pm2 start index.js` worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't define port with `-p` in PM2, there is no such option. Probably variable can do the work (as you mention in your comment):

```
port=4000 pm2 start index.js
```